# how to prevent git from committing file mode and owner

Tags: git, github

For learning and practical purpose, I git commit a complete joomla folder on remote linux server and then push the repo to github. Then I use Github Desktop to clone the repo to my local Mac. However, when I open the webpage I get a "mkdir():permission denied" error.

Comparatively, I download the repo's zip file from github then unzip it, the webpage has no problem this time.

I suppose the only difference between `.zip` and cloned repo is the former doesn't have a `.git` dir, all other files are just same, so it could only be a file owner/permission problem. To verify this, I change all file owner to root:root and permission to 0777, the webpage can be open this time.

So I think this confirms that when I do `git commit` on the remote server, git also records the files' permissions, how do I prevent this?

Comment: Git does not save file owner at all, and keeps track only of the executable bit.  Whatever your actual problem is, it's orthogonal to git itself.

Answer (score 2):

As @torec mentioned in his comment, git only track the execution bit and basically does not track chmod unless you tell it to.

```
# tell git to ignore filemode (chmod) as change,
git config core.fileMode false
```

> ***`core.fileMode`***
>    If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the
>    working copy are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT.
>    **True by default.**

---

#### ***`How to update executable bit?`***

```
# If you wish to set the executable bit use this comand
git update-index --chmod=+x <file>
```

> ***`--chmod=(+|-)x`***
>   Set the execute permissions on the updated files.

Comment: If the above does not work, check `fileMode` in your repo's `.git/config`.